# Weakening the assumption that an ideal is maximal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

This question is from ChI, $\S{3}$ of Serge Lang's Algebraic Number Theory.

Let $A$ be a commutative integral domain, integrally closed in its quotient field $K$, and let $E$ be a finite extension of $K$. Let $B$ be the integral closure if $A$ in $E$. Assume that $B=A[\alpha]$ for some element $\alpha$ and let $f(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. Let $\mathfrak p$ be a maximal ideal of $A$.

Lang shows that there is a bijection between the prime ideals $\mathfrak P$ of $B$ lying above $\mathfrak p$ and the irreducible factors $\overline{P}(X)$ of $\overline{f}(X)$, where $\overline{f}(X)$ is the polynomial induced from $f(X)$ by the canonical homomorphism $$A \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{p}=\overline{A}$$ Explicity, he shows that a prime $\mathfrak P$ corresponds to $\overline{P}$ if and only if $\mathfrak{P}$ is the kernel of the homomorphism $$A[\alpha]\rightarrow \overline{A}[\overline{\alpha}]$$ where $\overline{\alpha}$ is a root of $\overline{P}$.

After the proof he makes the following remark which I don't understand: "*the assumption that $\mathfrak p$ is maximal can be weakened to $\mathfrak p$ prime by localizing*."

Could someone explain  why this is true?

For example, if $\mathfrak p$ is a prime but non-maximal ideal of $A$ and we run the argument for the localizations $A_\mathfrak{p}$ and $B_\mathfrak{p}$ can we say that the required bijection exists for $A$ and $B$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this just mean after localization you have $p\in A_{p}$ be the maximal ideal?